# Creating VRT from PNG files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, convert, png, vrt, qgis-1

This is similar to a question asked by someone else, re OS tiles.  However, there is a difference!

I have a large number (over 10k) of georeferenced png files which I have mosaicked in ArcMap, but also want to be able to access them in other programs such as QGIS over the web and within a private network using GeoServer. I have tried creating VRT's with them, and sometimes it works, but sometimes it doesn't. It seems that on selecting over 200-odd png's, the vrt stops being created.

Is there a limit on the amount of rasters for a VRT?

The error message is:

> The process failed to start. Either the invoked program is missing, or
> you may have insufficient permissions to invoke the program.

and the code is:

```
gdalbuildvrt -allow_projection_difference 
"F:/Historic Buildings/GIS/Data/Mapping/Landranger/Raster/15k/Data/SX/SX.vrt" 
"F:/Historic Buildings/GIS/Data/Mapping/Landranger/Raster/15k/Data/SX/1.png" 
"F:/Historic Buildings/GIS/Data/Mapping/Landranger/Raster/15k/Data/SX/2.png" 
"F:/Historic Buildings/GIS/Data/Mapping/Landranger/Raster/15k/Data/SX/3.png" 
"F:/Historic Buildings/GIS/Data/Mapping/Landranger/Raster/15k/Data/SX/4.png" 
"F:/Historic Buildings/GIS/Data/Mapping/Landranger/Raster/15k/Data/SX/5.png" 
"F:/Historic Buildings/GIS/Data/Mapping/Landranger/Raster/15k/Data/SX/6.png" 
"F:/Historic Buildings/GIS/Data/Mapping/Landranger/Raster/15k/Data/SX/7.png"
```

with an additional +200 similarly addressed png's

I am using QGIS 1.8.0 Lisboa, on Windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 4):

See if you can do it sucessfully with a handful of files.

For me, it worked with 300 files. At first, I had to build individual vrts for each image to expand the colour information to rgba:

```
for %%N in (D:\Karten\gdal\gdal2tiles\NL25\*.tif) DO gdal_translate -of vrt -expand rgba %%N D:\Karten\gdal\gdal2tiles\NL25\%%~nN.vrt
```

Second run, I merged all those vrts to a single one:

```
gdalbuildvrt -allow_projection_difference index25.vrt NL25\*.vrt
```

Maybe the command line arguments are limited in character size, which I got around by using the wildcards.

Answer (score 2):

@AndreJ had the correct answer in their last statement.

It is a character limit.  If you use the wildcard it runs fine.  I just tried on 28000 tiffs and it ran no problem.