# Using wildcards to work around GDAL character limit

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, wildcard

I am attempting to use the 'Merge' & 'Create VRT' tools in QGIS 2.0 on 
a folder with 3000+ raster tiles in.

However whenever I try to perform this operation the following error appears:

> The process failed to start. Either the invoked program is missing, or
>   you may have insufficient permissions to invoke the program.

The process works when I select only a few tiles, so I can only assume it's due to a character restriction due to the number of files?

Upon searching the website for a solution I came across the concept of using 'Wildcards' to get around this problem:

[Having problems creating VRT in QGIS from png files](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53929/having-problems-creating-vrt-in-qgis-from-png-files)

However I cannot find any clear explanation on how to use them, and I don't have much experience with using OSGeo4W outside of the QGIS GUI.

Comment: you can launch the OSGeo4W command prompt to execute your gdal command lines. Probably better than using gdal through the QGIS GUI for "large projects"

Comment: Any pointers on how to use the OSGeo4W command prompt? For example could you post a simple example of creating a VRT?

Comment: for example : gdalbuildvrt doq_index.vrt doq/*.tif and if you type gdalbuildvrt alone, you should get the help.

Answer (score 5):

Create an input file list using a text editor (just one input filename per line), and use -input_file_list:

```
gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list mylist.txt my.vrt
```

This allows any number of input files.  You should be able to get to gdals command line tools by opening an osgeo4w shell from the start menu.