# merging raster aerials in QGIS issue

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, merge, aerial-photography

I follow the instructions [here](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/raster_mosaicing_and_clipping.html) very closely and yet every time QGIS gets caught in a loop. It takes a few small rasters totally less than 100mb and creates HUGE gb files and will not stop until python.exe is killed in task manager.

From one of the ecw's metadata :

`Driver
GDAL provider
ECW
ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 5.0)
Dataset Description
E:/work/1680_U/aerials/1680_naip/global_mapper/defbri_gm/500ft_clips/87.ecw
COLORSPACE=MULTIBAND
COMPRESSION_RATE_TARGET=1
VERSION=2
Band 1
Band 2
Band 3
Band 4
Dimensions
X: 36702 Y: 14147 Bands: 4
X : 18351,Y 7073
X : 9175,Y 3536
X : 4587,Y 1768
X : 2293,Y 884
X : 1146,Y 442
X : 573,Y 221
Origin
614731,4.61751e+06
Pixel Size
1,-1
No Data Value
*NoDataValue not set* 
Data Type
Byte - Eight bit unsigned integer
Pyramid overviews
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=utm +zone=16 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
Layer Extent (layer original source projection)
614730.9328588016796857,4603364.5349677717313170 : 651432.9328588016796857,4617511.5349677717313170
Band
Band 1
Band No
1
No Stats
No stats collected yet
Band
Band 2
Band No
2
No Stats
No stats collected yet
Band
Band 3
Band No
3
No Stats
No stats collected yet
Band
Band 4
Band No
4
No Stats
No stats collected yet`

Comment: Are your rasters adjacent without lot of empty space in between of them?

Comment: Post details about the rasters, i.e gdalinfo reports.

Comment: They are NAIP aerials (.sid or .ecw or .tif) sometimes with overlap and usually no empty space in between them.

Comment: can you please elaborate on how to run gdalinfo reports?

Comment: It is a command line tool http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html. Usage is simply `gdalinfo file_name.tif`.

Comment: tried multiple entries with the same error result http://i.imgur.com/ILnWZkj.png

Comment: You don't run it in QGIS, you run it in a command prompt. Don't worry about it, just post the text copied from the QGIS layer properties dialog -> metadata tab -> properties text - i.e. http://imgur.com/CJr015W (note, post the text, not a screenshot and edit your question to include this, don't post it in a comment)

Comment: maybe you should try with a vrt http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53929/having-problems-creating-vrt-in-qgis-from-png-files

Comment: @Luke I edited my op as instructed.

Comment: @radouxju all of these rasters have the same projection so I'm not sure doing vrt stuff will help. Also, it doesn't give any errors, it just gets caught in a loop and will make huge gb files without ending.

Answer (score 7):

I doubt your process "gets caught in a loop", I think it will just take a long time to complete as your rasters are actually quite large.

Those "small rasters totally less than 100mb" are roughly 2Gb uncompressed, *each*. The layer properties you included in your question show that particular raster has dimensions of 36702 cols, 14147 rows and 4 bands with an 8 bit (1 byte) data type. Therefore the uncompressed size of the raster is 36702*14147*4 bytes (1980.7 Mb).

ECW compression is quite effective...

Last year I was doing something similar and ended up with an output tiff which would have been 2TB if I did not use compression. The process took about a week to complete.

A couple of options:

1. In the [merge dialog](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/_images/719.png), make sure "creation options" is checked and select JPEG compression as the profile.

   - This will still take a long time and won't give quite as good compression rate as ECW.
   - You can get even better compression if you add another row to the creation options with name=PHOTOMETRIC and value=YCBCR, but JPEG YCBCR only works for three band images so you would have to extract the RGB or CIR bands first (i.e using a VRT).
   - Note that JPEG compression is lossy (as is ECW), but you will get better compression than with lossless compression methods such as DEFLATE and LZW.
2. Leave your rasters in ECW format and build a Virtual Raster (catalog).

   - This is the option above merge in the QGIS Raster->Miscellaneous menu.
   - This is my recommendation as the Virtual Raster is a simple text (xml) file that points to the original ECWs, so it takes up practically no disk space and will only take a few seconds to generate.

Answer (score 1):

ECW comes from Erdas and is not fully supported by GDAL without Erdas licence. According to the help :

> The ECW 4.x SDK from ERDAS is only free for image decompression. To
>   compress images it is necessary to build with the read/write SDK and
>   to provide an OEM licensing key at runtime which may be purchased from
>   ERDAS.

So you can decompress your image, but not recompress it in the same format, which is likely to be the reason why you end up with huge image on disk. You could however select another output type (e.g. tif), and set the compression type to DEFLATE or LZW (better, but less stable from my experience).

the other solution I propose is to create a vrt: those virtual file will create the mosaic that you can read in QGIS **without** creating a new image file, but it will behave like a mosaic for analysis.

Comment: The current GDAL ecw driver is read-only, so you can not write any output in that format, compressed or uncompressed.